# JNLP server returned 503 error

Tags: server, jnlp

I found some posts on this error but i can't get my JNLP to work. 
I try to access a JNLP located on server by the command : 
javaws http://:8081/jnlp/Composer.jnlp

The problem is that the server keeps returning 503 error even though my collegue is accessing it with not problem.
I understood that 503 error is a temporary unavailability of the server, but the previous point shows that the server is running fine (we tried several times).

The exact encapsulated error is :
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http:///jnlp/Composer.jnlp

What i tried to do is

- allow the adress of the server in the exception sites
- use the option to use IPV4 adress by default for JVM (i saw a post saying that there can be a bug using jre7 if u dont set the option -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true)
- restart server
- disable firewall.

My problem is that as my collegue can access it, it looks like a client configuration bug, not server.

Does somebody have an idea?

Thanks for your support.